# Kubuntu 20.04LTS on Acer Aspire A515-43-R19L not displaying properly until I log out and back in

Tags: boot, kubuntu, acer, display-manager

I just bought the A515-43-R19L Acer Aspire 5 laptop and went to install Kubuntu.
I added a SSD to the laptop which has Kubuntu installed, the Windows 10 installation is still installed in the built in memory.

When I boot up, the login screen to Kubuntu loads, minus the mouse cursor. Upon typing my password and logging in, I am met with a black screen, or a mostly black screen with a blank panel, and blank notification pop ups. I can launch firefox via Krunner or the application launcher (both of which are blank boxes) and whatever i can launch the only viewable part of it is the top window decoration.

If I log out, the login screen now displays a mouse cursor. And then when I login everything is working fine.

Here's a video of the process.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjDBAL8jWfU
Also there's weird static sometimes, but it doesn't impede my work it's just during boot or waking from sleep.

Sometimes this problem doesn't happen, but not many times.
Also if I tell grub to launch in recovery mode, do nothing and then boot like normal though recovery mode, this doesn't happen.

I'm very confused.

Comment: Update.I can replicate this issue by booting on battery. If I boot while plugged in it does not happen.

Comment: Also, another thing I have noticed. The backlit keyboard timeout is controlled by the bios. I went to the bios to disable the timeout. When booting from battery the keyboard stays lit. The timeout is back if I boot on battery